# error in vessel branch segmentation code

Tags: matlab

I am struggling with this problem since 2 days. Please help me out on this. I am working on vessel branch segmentation and I have got the code from [MathWorks central](http://www.mathworks.in/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36031-vessel-branch-segmentation).

Please download the submission from that site, and open the readme.txt

Before I got an error for converting tiff file to mat file but now it's working. Thank you for the quick reply to my post. But now I am getting the following error

```
Elapsed time is 0.987052 seconds. 
Index exceeds matrix dimensions. 
Error in VBSvesselMask (line 20) 
meanImg=mean(single(orgImg(:,:,windowSize+1:30)), 3); 
Error in VesselBranchSegmentation/CBestimateVesselMask (line 294) 
[appImg masks(1).img]= VBSvesselMask(orgImg);
Error while evaluating uimenu Callback
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dbstop if error` and check the size of `orgImg` at that point.

It seems the input is expected to be some sort of image stack (3D data or a stack of 2D images, such as a set of 2D images of the same area taken over time).  The error indicates that the size of your input image is smaller than what the code expects.

This line of code is the sticking point:

`orgImg(:,:,windowSize+1:30)`

For this to work, the size of third dimension of `orgImg` must be at least 30 and the value of `windowSize` should be appropriately set (somewhere between 0 and 29).  Looking at the original code, it appears you are supposed to use the `VBSreadtiff` function on a entire directory of images, to create an image stack for the code to work on.  Using a single grayscale or RGB image will not work.